# Unable to do Ctrl-S in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in Eclipse to save the current document, it doesn't save the document.  In fact, it skips and highlights the next "S" in the document, and continuing to press "s" will skip from "s" to "s" in the document.  I have reset my key bindings in eclipse, and even manually set both of the "Save" commands (one in File, the other in Application Category).  I've looked for key bindings that have only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but nothing pops out.

I don't have any scripts (like AutoHotkey) running.  I'm running Eclipse 4.2.1.
This randomly started happening, so I'm pretty sure its a bug on my side (especially with it being such a basic command on a solid IDE).

My guess is that its a plugin, or some other program interfering, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You may have switched to "Emacs" mode.  In Emacs, Ctrl-S is the inline-search key.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

and look at the "Scheme:" control.

It probably should say "Default" unless you know what you are doing.  If that's not it, type "Ctrl+S" in the large field under the Scheme control and see what shows up.  If you don't see the "Save" command, you'll need to configure it.

Comment: I am on default, and Ctrl-S is there.  Something is blocking all of the basic Ctrl commands (Like Ctrl-S, Ctrl-F, Ctrl-X and so forth).  I've ended up having to redefine all of them and memorize what they are.